PL/pgSQL function doesn't work via supabase REST API Client
I'm using supabase for my golang application. For one specific function I need to do some database stuff and decide to use supabase rpc call.
If I call the function within supabase SQL Editor it runs as expected. If I call the same function via REST Api it doesn't work (go with supabase-go or Postman with REST). There is especially one SELECT which can't find any values. If I extract that SQL and execute it in SQL Editor (with same values) - it runs as expected.
I'm searching for hours now and can't make it...:
This is my function until the point the exception is thrown:
CREATE
OR REPLACE FUNCTION place_order (
  client_id integer,
  consumer_phone text,
  order_items order_item[]
) RETURNS order_result AS $body$
declare
  i integer;
  order_id integer;
  item order_item;
  current_product integer;
  is_menu boolean;
  temp_menu_product menus_products%rowtype;
  total_price double precision := 0.0;
  product_price double precision := 0.0;
  extra_price double precision := 0.0;
BEGIN
  --CREATE ORDER HEAD
  insert into orders values (default, client_id, consumer_phone, default, 'new')
  returning id into order_id;

  IF order_id <= 0 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error while creating the order for client: % and consumer: %', client_id, consumer_phone;
  END IF;

  FOREACH item in ARRAY order_items LOOP
    
    item.item_name := item.item_name::text;
    item.quantity := item.quantity::integer;
    item.size := item.size::size;
    item.extras := item.extras::text[];

    --Reset loop variables
    current_product := 0;
    is_menu := false;

RAISE LOG 'Before product lookup - item_name: %, quantity: %, size: %', item.item_name, item.quantity, item.size;

    --Find the item in our products or menus
    SELECT id, menu, price
      INTO current_product, is_menu, product_price
      FROM (SELECT id, false as menu, price
              FROM products
            WHERE TRIM(UPPER(name)) = TRIM(UPPER(item.item_name))
              AND size = item.size
              AND valid_from <= NOW()
              AND valid_to >= NOW()
            union all
              SELECT id, true as menu, price
              FROM menus
              WHERE TRIM(UPPER(name)) = TRIM(UPPER(item.item_name))
                AND size = item.size
                AND valid_from <= NOW()
                AND valid_to >= NOW()) as product
    LIMIT 1;

RAISE LOG 'After product lookup - current_product: %, is_menu: %, product_price: %', current_product, is_menu, product_price;

    IF current_product IS NULL then
      RAISE exception 'Error: Cannot find a product or menu for order_item: %', item.item_name;
    END IF;

And the custom types for clarity:
CREATE TYPE order_item AS (
  item_name text,
  quantity integer,
  size size,
  extras text[]
);

create type size as enum (
  'S',
  'M',
  'L',
  'XL',
  'XXL'
);

As mentioned the problem occurs in the larger SELECT. This works without any problem:
SELECT
place_order (
1,
'+491605293532',
ARRAY[
ROW ('Pommes', 1, 'M', ARRAY['Mayo'])::order_item
]
);

OR to explicitly try the SELECT:
SELECT
  id,
  menu,
  price
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      false as menu,
      price
    FROM
      products
    WHERE
      TRIM(UPPER(name)) = TRIM(UPPER('Pommes'))
      AND size = 'M'
      AND valid_from <= NOW()
      AND valid_to >= NOW()
    union all
    SELECT
      id,
      true as menu,
      price
    FROM
      menus
    WHERE
      TRIM(UPPER(name)) = TRIM(UPPER('Pommes'))
      AND size = 'M'
      AND valid_from <= NOW()
      AND valid_to >= NOW()
  ) as product
LIMIT
  1;

But via REST API I'm always getting the exception:
POST rest/v1/rpc/place_order
JSON Body:
{
  "client_id" : 1,
  "consumer_phone" : "+491605293532",
  "order_items" : [ {
    "item_name" : "Pommes",
    "quantity" : 1,
    "size" : "M",
    "extras" : [ "Mayo" ]
  }]
}


That's the self generated error message: {
"code": "P0001",
"details": null,
"hint": null,
"message": "Error: Cannot find a product or menu for order_item: Pommes" }

And that's what logged before and after the select:


Thanks Erwin for helpful improvements :). At the end it fails due to missing RLS Permission. Within supabase I’m in Admin Role, via Rest I used Anon Key and therefore had no access to read those tables.

Consider this rewrite:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION place_order (
     client_id      int
   , consumer_phone text
   , order_items    order_item[]
   )
  RETURNS order_result
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   i               int;
   order_id        int;
   item            order_item;
   current_product int;
   is_menu         bool;
   temp_menu_product menus_products;
   total_price     float := 0;
   product_price   float := 0;
   extra_price     float := 0;
BEGIN
   -- CREATE ORDER HEAD
   INSERT INTO orders  -- spell out target columns !!!
   VALUES (DEFAULT, client_id, consumer_phone, DEFAULT, 'new')
   RETURNING id
   INTO order_id;

   IF order_id > 0 THEN  -- all good, do nothing
   ELSE  -- also catch null (or "no row")
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error while creating the order for client: % and consumer: %', client_id, consumer_phone;
   END IF;

   FOREACH item IN ARRAY order_items
   LOOP
      /* all pointless noise
      item.item_name := item.item_name::text;
      item.quantity := item.quantity::integer;
      item.size := item.size::size;
      item.extras := item.extras::text[];
      
      -- reset loop variables
      current_product := 0;
      is_menu := false;
      */

      RAISE LOG 'Before product lookup - item_name: %, quantity: %, size: %', item.item_name, item.quantity, item.size;

      -- find item in products
      SELECT INTO current_product, is_menu, product_price
                  id             , false  , price
      FROM   products
      WHERE  trim(upper(name)) = trim(upper(item.item_name))  -- inefficient!
      AND    size = item.size
      AND    now() BETWEEN valid_from AND valid_to
      LIMIT  1;  -- dubious without ORDER BY

      IF NOT FOUND THEN
         -- find item in menus
         SELECT INTO current_product, is_menu, product_price
                     id             , true   , price
         FROM   menus
         WHERE  trim(upper(name)) = trim(upper(item.item_name))  -- inefficient!
         AND    size = item.size
         AND    now() BETWEEN valid_from AND valid_to;
         LIMIT  1;  -- dubious without ORDER BY
      END IF;

      RAISE LOG 'After product lookup - current_product: %, is_menu: %, product_price: %', current_product, is_menu, product_price;

      IF NOT FOUND THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error: Cannot find a product or menu for order_item: %', item.item_name;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
$func$;

Related:

Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?
Special variable FOUND not set properly?

